# How to pass queryset with exclude param in django-filter extension

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm using [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [django-pure-pagination](https://github.com/jamespacileo/django-pure-pagination) extensions

```
class BuyFilterView(PaginationMixin, FilterView):
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    template_name = "buy_filter.html"
    context_object_name = "goods"
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BuyFilterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = Cart.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return context


class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    country = ChoiceFilter(choices=country_values)
    brand = ChoiceFilter(choices=brand_values)
    type = ChoiceFilter(choices=type_values)

    class Meta:
        model = Goods
        fields = {
            'country': ['exact'],
            'brand': ['exact'],
            'type': ['exact'],
        }
```

Some items in `Goods` model have blank price value. I want to exclude them from queryset. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly modify your BuyFilterView and get_context_data() to explicitly call ProductFilter and use combination of MultipleObjectMixin and TemplateView:

```
class BuyFilterView(PaginationMixin, MultipleObjectMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "buy_filter.html"
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BuyFilterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = Cart.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        context['goods'] = ProductFilter(request.GET,
                                         queryset=Goods.objects.exclude(price=''))
        return context
```

Another, maybe even more clean option is to use ListView and override its get_queryset() method:

```
class BuyFilterView(PaginationMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "buy_filter.html"
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Goods.objects.exclude(price=''))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BuyFilterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = Cart.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

Comment: Not really since you are explicitly defining your context data in get_context_data(). You can use TemplateView instead.

Comment: Looks like TemplateView doesn't implement MultipleObjectMixin which is used for pagination. Do you happen to know how to make it with pagination?

Comment: Ok, you can either add MultipleObjectMixin or use ListView instead of TemplateView and override its get_queryset() method. See my updated answer.

Comment: Finally got it work with FilterView. I need it to have form built in filter object. For some reason had to set `model` parameter of FilterView, even though it is declared in Meta class of my filter. Thanks for your help.